# Rollback Transaction when concurrency check fails

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure which does a lot of probing of the database to determine if some records should be updated

Each record (Order) has a `TIMESTAMP` called `[RowVersion]`

I store the candidate record ids and RowVersions in a temporary table called `@Ids`

```
DECLARE @Ids TABLE (id int, [RowVersion] Binary(8))
```

I get the count of candidates with the the following

```
DECLARE @FoundCount int
SELECT @FoundCount = COUNT(*) FROM @Ids
```

Since records may change from when i `SELECT` to when i eventually try to `UPDATE`, i need a way to check concurrency and `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` if that check fails

**What i have so far**

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- create new combinable order group
INSERT INTO CombinableOrders DEFAULT VALUES 

-- update orders found into new group
UPDATE Orders
    SET Orders.CombinableOrder_Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    FROM Orders AS Orders
    INNER JOIN @Ids AS Ids 
      ON Orders.Id = Ids.Id 
      AND Orders.[RowVersion] = Ids.[RowVersion] 

-- if the rows updated dosnt match the rows found, then there must be a concurrecy issue, roll back
IF (@@ROWCOUNT != @FoundCount)
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    set @Updated = -1       
END
ELSE
    COMMIT
```

From the above, i'm filtering the `UPDATE` with the stored `[RowVersion]` this will skip any records that have since been changed (hopefully)

However i'm not quite sure if i'm using transactions or optimistic concurrency in regards to `TIMESTAMP` correctly, or if there are better ways to achieve my desired goals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to understand what logic you are trying to implement.

But, if you absolutely must perform several non-atomic actions in a procedure and make sure that the whole block of code is not executed again while it is running (for example, by another user), consider using [`sp_getapplock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx).

> Places a lock on an application resource.

Your procedure may look similar to this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[YourProcedure]
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    BEGIN TRY

        DECLARE @VarLockResult int;
        EXEC @VarLockResult = sp_getapplock
            @Resource = 'UniqueStringFor_app_lock',
            @LockMode = 'Exclusive',
            @LockOwner = 'Transaction',
            @LockTimeout = 60000,
            @DbPrincipal = 'public';

        IF @VarLockResult >= 0
        BEGIN
            -- Acquired the lock

            -- perform your complex processing

            -- populate table with IDs
            -- update other tables using IDs
            -- ...

        END;

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH;

END
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer however im actually trying to determine if some other query has changed the order before i do an update at the end of my sp

Comment: I re-read your question again. It looks to me that what you are doing is correct. MSDN [`rowversion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms182776.aspx) article has an example, where they use `OUTPUT` clause in the `UPDATE` statement. They remember updated rows in a separate table variable, which then is used to count how many rows were updated. You use `@@ROWCOUNT` for this purpose. I can't tell which method is better. If you really want to update several Orders together only if none of them have been touched during your processing, your solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

When you SELECT the data, try using HOLDLOCK and UPDLOCK while inside of an explicit transaction. It's going to mess with the concurrency of OTHER transactions but not yours.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx